# Smarty MYSQL Array assoc id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, smarty

I have my php code like this:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT p.* FROM products AS p "
                      ."INNER JOIN products_cat_link AS cpl ON cpl.Product_ID = p.id "
                      ."WHERE cpl.Category_ID = '$forcat' "
                      ."ORDER BY p.id");

$products_row = array();
$products_images = array();

    while($prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) {
            if (isset($prow['id'])) {
                    $product['info'] = $prow;
                $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_images WHERE `Product_id` = '$prow[id]' ORDER BY id");
                while($irow = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) { 
                    $images_result[] = $irow;
                }
                    $product['images'] = $images_result;
                    $products_images[] = $product;
            }
            $product = '';
            $images_result = '';
    }
$smarty->assign('products_images',$products_images);
```

That makes an array like this

```
Array ( 
    [info] => array (
        [id] = 1
        [name] = abc
    ) 
    [images] => array (
        [Products_Image_Thumb] = 1a.jpg
        [Products_Image_Big] = 1b.jpg
    )
)
```

But i cannot get the images information with smarty:

```
{foreach from=$products_images key=cols item=image name=images}
{if $cols % 4 == 0}<div>{/if}
<a href="images/products/big/{$image.images.Products_Image_Big}">
<img src="images/products/thumb/{$image.images.Products_Image_Thumb}" alt="Click to Enlarge" title="Click to Enlarge" width="87" height="65" style="margin:3px;" /></a>
{if $cols % 4 == 3}</div>{/if}
{if $smarty.foreach.images.last}</div>{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off the comment on my previous answer, this should work. However it is untested and I haven't used Smarty in a while.

```
{foreach from=$products_images key=cols item=product name=products}
    {if $cols % 4 == 0}<div>{/if}
    {foreach from=$product.images item=image name=images}
        <a href="images/products/big/{$image.Products_Image_Big}">
        <img src="images/products/thumb/{$image.Products_Image_Thumb}" alt="Click to Enlarge" title="Click to Enlarge" width="87" height="65" style="margin:3px;" /></a>
    {/foreach}
    {if $cols % 4 == 3}</div>{/if}
    {if $smarty.foreach.products.last}</div>{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Gallery_Image_Big and Gallery_Image_Thumb are the real keys... i was just doing examples

Comment: Sorry, am I right in guessing that the images aren't displaying and you want them to or is it another issue? I'm not sure what you mean by *i cannot get the images information with smarty*.

Comment: ya the images are not showing, nothing is printing in  the {$image.images.Gallery_Image_Big}

Comment: OK, can you tell me what the output is if you just put a `{$image|print_r}` in the foreach loop?

Comment: Array ( [info] => Array ( [id] => 1 [Product_Title] => Caterpilla [Product_URL] => Caterpilla [Product_Size] => Null [Product_Suit] => Children [Product_Cover] => 1 [Product_Description] => Test Castle [Product_Price] => 50 [Product_OPrice] => Null ) [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [Product_id] => 1 [Product_Image_Thumb] => thumb_56_Sam.jpg [Product_Image_Big] => big_56_Sam.jpg ) ) )

Comment: i changed it but still shows nothing... <a href="images/products/big/{$image.images.Product_Image_Big}">
                            <img src="images/products/thumb/{$image.images.Product_Image_Thumb}" alt="Click to Enlarge"